# UIView and Model View Controller (MVC) pattern

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm trying to develop an App to hear music from the iPod (similar to the AddMusic example). I have a ViewController with a custom view which has some graphics and buttons to manage the music playback. With a navigationController I can choose a list from the iPod music and show it to an UITable (as the AddMusic).

Now I have to program all the methods to manage the list of music to play, stop, isPlaying, duration, etc.

My question is:

In order to follow the Model View Controller pattern, where is the best place to program all that methods (to manage music) that are not views, in the main ViewController or in the View where I have the buttons that interact with the user?

I think the answer should be the main ViewController but in that case how can I access that methods from the view where I have the user interface buttons and I'm managing some graphics? because the UIView don't have something like 'parentViewController'.

Thank you very much.

Kanick

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a class that inherits exactly that main ViewController. And in the second view controller you can create an instance of that class. Eventually that object will ave all the information you have in the main view controller.

Comment: ThankYou @Mikayil, I've tried your idea. I really don't have two view controllers. I have 1 viewController (my mainViewControler) and a view (that is [mainViewController setView: myView]). Anyway, I did what  you suggested I declared a new class ->  @interface inheritsFromMyMainViewController : myMainViewController{}. Ok, I can access the methods of the myMainViewController but not its ivars (maybe I made something wrong) because of the (id)sender is the myView, and another point is that I need to deal with the currentTime in order to move the graphics. I am right?

Comment: The convention to reach ivars of an object is by @property. If you have neither declared properties for the ivars nor getter and/or setter methods you can no way access them. So please make sure you use either way. I of course suggest using @property way as it makes possible using dot syntax. But I did not understand the relationsship between currentTime and move Graphics stuff.